# Multiple relationships on same table with two column Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

If the bookstore does not have any books in stock, this bookstore can purchase books from the other bookstore it is contracted with.

**book_transfers** table is as follows.

```
ID | sender_bookstore_id | delivery_bookstore_id 
1  | 2                   | 3  
2  | 1                   | 2  
3  | 3                   | 1
```

**books** table

```
ID | store_name  
1  | London Garden Book Store
2  | Englaland Cafe Book
3  | Domesday Book Store
```

Two-column `sender_bookstore_id` and `delivery_bookstore_id` belong to the same table. The name of this table books.

My Controller code is below:

```
$data = BookTransfer::join('books', 'books.id', '=', 'book_transfers.sender_bookstore_id')
         ->select(
             'book_transfers.*',
             'book_transfers.sender_bookstore_id as sender_id',
             'book_transfers.delivery_bookstore_id as delivery_id',
             'books.store_name as sender_store_name'
         )
         ->groupBy('book_transfers.id')
         ->get();
         return $data;
```

I can only get **`sender_store_name`** here. I need to add extra code for `delivery_store_name` in the above controller But I don't know how to get **`delivery_store_name`**.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the datas by `join`, you can `join` the same `books` table again, and alias it another name:

```php
BookTransfer::join('books AS sender_books', 'sender_books.id', '=', 'book_transfers.sender_bookstore_id')
            ->join('books AS delivery_books', 'deliery_books.id', '=', 'book_transfers.delivery_bookstore_id')
            ->select(
                 'book_transfers.*',
                 'book_transfers.sender_bookstore_id AS sender_id',
                 'book_transfers.delivery_bookstore_id AS delivery_id',
                 'sender_books.store_name AS sender_store_name',
                 'delivery_books.store_name AS delivery_store_name'
             )
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Good solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using relation would be much more simpler.

```
// BookTransfer Model
public function sender(){
     return $this->belongsTo(Book::class, 'sender_bookstore_id');
}

public function delivery(){
     return $this->belongsTo(Book::class, 'delivery_bookstore_id ');
}
```

Your controller would look like this

```
$data = BookTransfer::with(['sender', 'delivery'])->get();
```